# In django whenever I try to run the server, I want to see the login page first, but I am seeing the index page

Tags: django, authentication

I am attaching my code in views and urls.py. Whenever the server runs, I want to see the login page first, but I am seeing an error that this page is not working.

```py
#views.py
def loginPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Username OR password is incorrect')

        context = {}
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context)
```

```py
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
   
    path('', views.loginPage, name="login"),
    path('index/',views.index,name="index"),
```

Comment: Could you provide the error you are getting, please?

Comment: provide some error.

Comment: I am not getting any error. on the port http://127.0.0.1:8000/ I am seeing an error that page is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass @login_required decorator in your view. If you don't want to pass this decorator in your every view there are second way which you can do using middleware. In middleware you check the user is authenticated or not. If yes it redirects user to index page other way to login page. Here is an example:

Create middleware.py file and write this code inside it:

```py
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect


class LoginCheckMiddleWare(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        modulename = view_func.__module__
        user = request.user # Who is the current user ?
        if user.is_authenticated:
                return redirect(reverse('index-page'))
        else:
            if request.path == reverse('login_page') or modulename == 'django.contrib.auth.views':
                pass
            else:
                return redirect(reverse('login_page'))
```

After that add this line inside `MIDDLEWARE` in `settings.py` file:

`'folder.middleware.LoginCheckMiddleWare',` instead of folder write your middleware file located folder